# I can't load Spanish/German special characters

Tags: mysql, load, utf8mb4

Installed mysql-installer-community-8.0.11.0.msi this week, on a Windows 10 machine and am stuck loading Spanish names.

A row with `Reynaldo Cantú` fails with loader message:

> ERROR 1300 (HY000) at line 4: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'Reynaldo Cant'

Same with upside-down question marks.

If I remove that row, all the other names with accented vowels such as `Chacón`, are truncated starting with the accented vowel.

All web searches on the subject say, use utf8mb4.  So I went from not specifying a character set, to having added utf8mb4 everywhere I can think of. But the with
same result.

My database is `utf8mb4`.
My create table is
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T_JackArtist;

```
CREATE TABLE T_JackArtist( -- Table of people recorded  
    RID     INT PRIMARY KEY,        -- T_JackArtist unique row ID
    Name    VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL  ,    -- Name of person recorded
    Note    VARCHAR(256)  NOT NULL, -- Note
    AKA1    VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL,  -- Name of person recorded
    Track_Changed   DATETIME        NOT NULL DEFAULT Current_Timestamp,
    Track_Userid    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Init'
) 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

My MySql.exe load command is

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\Mysql.exe" Jack -h xxx8 -u xxx --password=xxx --batch --raw --local-infile --default-character-set=utf8 < T_JackArtist.cmd
```

with T_JackArtist.cmd

```
USE Jack;
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Dan\\Jack\\MySql\\Schema\\import\\T_JackArtist.txt' INTO TABLE T_JackArtist IGNORE 1 LINES ;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the `LOAD DATA` statement, include `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Make sure the bytes in the file are really utf8, not latin1:

- `ú` hex in utf8/utf8mb4:  `C3FA`
- `ú` hex in latin1:  `FA`

See also 'truncated' in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)